# Convention for continuing a method signature to new line

Tags: python

Consider the following versions of code:

```
def __init__(self, broker, group, offset='largest', commit_every_x_ms=1000,
             parts=None):
    #       ^
    pass
```

vs

```
def __init__(self, broker, group, offset='largest',
        commit_every_t_ms=1000, parts=None):
    #  ^
    pass
```

I think the second option looks better as it can conserve lines required for functions with very large names, but which one will be considered more pythonic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to `PEP 0008` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
Yes:

# Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)

# More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)

# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)

No:

# Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)

# Further indentation required as indentation is not distinguishable.
def long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two, var_three,
    var_four):
    print(var_one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) (PEP-0008) that has recommendations for things like this. As stated there:

Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator is after the operator, not before it. Some examples:

```
class Rectangle(Blob):

def __init__(self, width, height,
             color='black', emphasis=None, highlight=0):
    if (width == 0 and height == 0 and
            color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or
            highlight > 100):
        raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
    if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
                                       emphasis is None):
        raise ValueError("I don't think so -- values are %s, %s" %
                         (width, height))
    Blob.__init__(self, width, height,
                  color, emphasis, highlight)
```

Also check out the [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) section for more examples.